# Format fails to copy text properties from the format-string for adjacent %-sequences

Tags: formatting, text-properties

Take a look at this example:

```
(format (concat "%s" (propertize "%s" 'face 'error)) "foo" "bar")
"foobar"

(format (concat "%s " (propertize "%s" 'face 'error)) "foo" "bar")
#("foo bar" 4 7 (face error))
```

And the documentation of `format` explicitly states:

> Text properties, if any, are copied from the format-string to the produced text.

Why is that?

I know I can work around this with:

```
(format "%s%s" "foo" (propertize "bar" 'face 'error))
#("foobar" 3 6 (face error))
```

Or even:

```
(concat "foo" (propertize "bar" 'face 'error))
#("foobar" 3 6 (face error))
```

But my original use case is a bit more complex than this.

---

#### Edit

A probably more general example is the following:

```
(format (concat (propertize "%s" 'face 'bold)
                "" ; any non-empty string works
                (propertize "%s" 'face 'error))
        "foo" "bar")
#("foobar" 0 6 (face bold))
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, or an enhancement request. Wait a bit, to see what others say, then consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Observation: Text properties are copied only when there is a literal character in the format string, e.g., `(format (propertize "\s%s" 'face 'error) "foo")` gives `#(" foo" 0 4 (face error))`.

Comment: @Tobias No I think it's more about literals between two otherwise adjacent %-sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it was a [bug](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=32404) which has now been fixed in [this](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?h=emacs-26&id=71c92d89137b7fdde6c2bd4bed9b8dfda5fa53dd) commit.